Ubuntu 24.04 + Odoo 17.0 instalation - error: externally-managed-environment
I use Digital Ocean with an Ubuntu 24.04 (LTS) x64 droplet + this script https://github.com/Yenthe666/InstallScript/tree/17.0
While installing the following error appears.
If I disable the externally-managed-environment I get another error regarding idna 3.6 (see second error below).
Has anybody managed to resolve this issue?
Thank you!
---- Install python packages/requirements ----

error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed

╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install

python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to

install.

If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,

create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.

Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make

sure you have python3-full installed.

If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,

it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a

virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.

See /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.

hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

idna error
Installing collected packages: idna, greenlet, geoip2, ebaysdk, docutils, decorator, chardet, beautifulsoup4, Babel, zeep, vobject, reportlab, ofxparse, gevent, freezegun, cryptography, pyopenssl
Attempting uninstall: idna
Found existing installation: idna 3.6
ERROR: Cannot uninstall idna 3.6, RECORD file not found. Hint: The package was installed by debian.


This question is similar to: How do I solve "error: externally-managed-environment" every time I use pip 3?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
